# como adjuntar imagen a traves de comando slash y subirla a imgur api con python

Tags: python, discord.py

Estoy tratando de programar un pequeño bot que haga el trabajo de cargar la imagen adjuntando la imagen de discord con el comando de barra, pero tengo un pequeño problema y cuando agrego el comando en discord y subo la imagen con el archivo adjunto , la imagen no esta publicada, no se donde puede estar el problema

esto es lo que no me funciona
[image]

y no sube la imagen algo estoy haciendo mal

en el símbolo del sistema me da error
[image]

Mi código en python:

```
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)
@slash.slash(
    name="imgur", description="imgur",
    options=[
        create_option(
                name="image",
                description="Attach an Image",
                required=True,
                option_type=11, #Attachment
                
        )
               
                  
                
             ])


async def _imgur(ctx:SlashContext, image):

    await ctx.defer()

    with open("configuracion.json") as f:
        config = json.load(f)
        
        
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + config["token_imgur"],}
        
      
        params = {
            'layout': u'blog',
            'title':f'Escribe un titulo', 
            'description':'Escribe una descripción',
            'name':'Escribe algun nombre',
            'image': base64.b64encode(open(f'{image}', 'rb').read())}
        r = requests.post(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', headers=headers, data=params)
        data = r.json()["data"]["link"]
        id = r.json()["data"]["id"]
        borrar = r.json()["data"]["deletehash"]

        print(image)

    

    
    await ctx.send(f"{image}\n\n{id}")
```

¿Alguien podría echarme una mano?, ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Estás usando pycord? Si es así, creo que deberías indicarlo. También deberías añadir la etiqueta `discord.py` a tu pregunta.

Comment: no, no uso pycord

Comment: Como lo podria hacer funcionar?

Comment: No se en que estoy haciendo mal 

Comment: Desconozco la solución, pero podrías probar a convertir el `attachment` (tu parámetro "image") a un archivo (`File`) antes de intentar subirlo a imgur: `file = await image.to_file()`. Y ya después `'image': base64.b64encode(open(f'{file}', 'rb').read())`. También podrías probar a usar [este cliente python](https://pypi.org/project/imgur-python/) para la API de imgur, para facilitar la interacción con la API.

Comment: aparece este error https://i.imgur.com/dbBnN8B.png con un codigo
 No such file or directory: '1104435213041406073'

Comment: Estuve haciendo pruebas y conseguí *"encodear"* la imagen con estas 2 líneas: https://i.imgur.com/nYIz1ui.png. Supongo que ya con eso puedes subir la imagen como estás haciendo

Comment: Podrias pasarme el codigo?, si no es mucha molestia 

Comment: `file = await imagen.to_file()` y `encoded_file = base64.b64encode(file.fp.read())`

Comment: Nada, no funciona, muchas gracias de todos modos